# Средний вектор для вывода из нейронной сети

Tags: нейронные-сети, векторы

Я занимаюсь структурированием фото и видео данных по некоторым параметрам. У меня есть нейронная сеть, которая на вход получает фото, а на выходе - 512-и мерный вектор. Для моей задачи надо найти общий вектор для нескольких изображений. То есть, сейчас у меня есть n 512-и размерных векторов. Как мне найти общий вектор, который будет характеризовать всю группу изображений? Сейчас для решения такой задачи я просто складываю все соответствующие элементы векторов и делю на их количество (нахожу среднее арифметическое, если так можно сказать)

Comment: если надо просто найти средний вектор ничего не сравнивая то среднее арифметическое, пожалуй, как раз то что вам нужно...

Comment: @MaxU, я не уточнил, зачем мне это надо. После того, как я найду среднее значение векторов, я должно буду по этому значению определить, к какому из средних векторов ближе новое изображение

Comment: вы случаем не пытаетесь самостоятельно реализовать задачу кластеризации?

Comment: Фактически, этим я и занимаюсь)

Comment: А почему бы не воспользоваться готовыми реализациями?

Comment: Можете предоставить ссылки на эти готовые реализации? А так, мне интересно самому это сделать, новый опыт всё таки

Comment: [Выбирайте ;-)](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html)

Comment: Возможно, я не совсем верно выразился. Или выразился верно, но просто понимаю что-то не так. Вот моя задача: я обрабатываю посты ВК, каждой группе соответствует свой набор картинок и текстов. Так вот,  мой алгоритм среди всех этих групп находит наиболее близкую к заданной. На этом этапе всё действительно выглядит как простая кластеризация. Но! 1)Групп только сейчас ~40K. 2)В дальнейшем они будут добавляться. И они добавляются автоматически, то есть, я не смогу переучивать класторизатор каждый раз, это слишком неэффективно по ресурсам. Я где-то ошибаюсь?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84269/discussion-between-maxu-and-vladf).

Answer (score 1):

Из долгой дискуссии в комментариях удалось выяснить дополнительные подробности:

в решении используется сверточная нейронная сеть архитектуры VGG19, которая преобразует картинки на входе в 512 признаков, т.е. на выходе получается 2D матрица размерности (число картинок на входе x 512 [столбцы]).

Далее считается среднее арифметическое полученной матрицы по столбцам (признакам) для того чтобы получить вектор, состоящий из 512 значений (признаков), который будет средним для группы.

После этого при помощи "cosine distance" находиться матрица расстояний между всеми парами групп (векторов) и находится пара с минимальным расстоянием, т.е. наиболее похожую по найденным 512 признакам.

Данный подход представляется мне вполне рабочим.